# Questions regarding two metrics equivalence

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have a metric space $(X, d)$ and $(X, d^*)$.

Also suppose that $d(x, y) \leqslant d^*(x, y)$ for all $x, y \in X$.

Now let $r > 0$ be given. The textbook claims that if we set $r^* = r$, we have
$B_r(x) \subset B_{r^*}^*(x)$, where $B_r(x)$ is a ball centered at $x \in X$ in the metric space $(X, d)$ with the radius $r$ and $B_{r^*}^*(x)$ is a ball centered at $x \in X$ in the metric space $(X, d^*)$ with the radius $r^*$.

I am trouble understanding why $B_r(x) \subset B_{r^*}^*(x)$. Because if $B_r(x) = \{y: d(x, y) < r\}$ and $B_{r^*}^*(x) = \{y: d^*(x,y) < r\}$, since $d(x, y) \leqslant d^*(x, y)$ wouldn't $B_r(x)$ be a bigger set than $B_{r^*}^*(x)$ (since any $y$ would have a bigger value in $d^*$ thus the set $B_{r^*}^*(x)$ is more limited.)?

What am I not seeing here?

Comment: Indeed, if we always have $d(x,y) \leqslant d^{\ast}(x,y)$, then $B^{\ast}_r(x) \subset B_r(x)$. If you haven't misread, it's a typo in the book.

Comment: @DanielFischer Then can we show rigorously that $B_r^*(x) \subset B_r(x)$ instead of relying on intuition?

Comment: Sure, $$y \in B^{\ast}_r(x) \implies d^{\ast}(x,y) < r \implies d(x,y) < r \implies y \in B_r(x).$$